# Euler–Lagrange equation: Three functions of single variable with higher derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $f_{i} \colon [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be three times differentiable. I need to consider a functional $S$ of the following form:
\begin{equation*}
S(f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}) = \int_{0}^{L}L(t, f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},f_{1}',f_{2}',f_{3}',f_{1}'',f_{2}'',f_{3}'',f_{1}''',f_{2}''',f_{3}''')\,dt,
\end{equation*}
where an apostrophe denotes differentiation with respect to the variable $t$.

I would like to write down the corresponding Euler–Lagrange equation(s). I tried to derive the result from the more general case treated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Several_functions_of_several_variables_with_higher_derivatives), but I got rather confused by the index notation. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying [single function of single variable with higher derivatives case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_single_variable_with_higher_derivatives) from the page to each function $f_i$ separately and you get
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial f_i}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f_i'}+\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f_i''}-\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f_i'''}=0.
$$

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that going from a single function to several functions there is no interaction between the functions. I think the result is more obvious if you go from the several functions, several variables, higher derivatives case and just say most of the partial derivatives are $0$.

Comment: @Arthur It is obvious there are no interactions between the functions $f_i, f_j$ since we are just taking the derivative along $f_i$-direction (similar to directional derivative in multivariable calculus).

Comment: I still think the other way is a much more immediate and obvious corollary. I don't see at a glance that generalising from one function to many is as easy as just giving each of them their own separate EL-equation.